# WP 8.1 Push notifications - Invalid Client Secret

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm following this guide (msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465407) to implement push notifications on my app, but it seems to be outdated since I can't find the client secret as shown in this image (https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC737349.png).

If I try to register using the password i can generate at (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), I get an error message.

**Request:**

```
 POST /accesstoken.srf HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Host: https://login.live.com

    grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ms-app%3a%2f%2fS-1-15-2-3747961549-[...]&client_secret=[???]&scope=notify.windows.com
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Invalid client secret"
}
```

So, where to find this client secret?

Answer (score 0):

You must login into the microsoft dev dashboard, create a new app (you don't have to load a .xap file, you just need to put in a name and all those stuffs...)

After that, click on the app you just created: on the left, select "services" from the menu and then click on the "push notification" link.

Finally, on the page you will see now, click the "live services website" link that you will see on the second text paragraph. you should now see a page with your secret code.

let me know if you resolved the problem, cheers!

Comment: I've already done that but on the "live services website" there is no client secret required for authentication. http://i.imgur.com/JqGtQtP.png As you can see the live services website provide only Passwords and Private keys.

Comment: that's strange.. under the section "application secrets" i can find my client secret key, and i can't even see the column "type"
i'm sorry, but i don't know what else to look for

Comment: Yep, no problem. Thanks for checking it. But it's really very strange that we have different informations provided on the website.